# Not able to get some autosuggestions for inner class members in std::map in visual studio code (Intellisense)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, stdmap, std-pair

I am currently making a reverse map class `bidir_map`. The code can be compiled using GCC in the terminal so the types and members should be in scope but Intellisense is not giving autosuggestion for specific parts of the code e.g. `std::pair<K,V>` members (but it does give suggestions to `std::map` members). What is the reason for this and is there any way to make Intellisense to give suggestions on the `std::pair<K,V>`'s inner structure through `std::map`?

```
#ifndef BIDIR_MAP_H
#define BIDIR_MAP_H
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility> // std::pair
#include <exception>
using std::map;

template <typename K, typename V>
class bidir_map : public map<K,V> {
    using map<K,V>::map; 
    using map<K,V>::at;

public:
    const K& at(const V v) const {
        auto it = this->lookup(this->cbegin(), v); // <-- vscode displays `<unknown> bidir_map<K, V>::cbegin`
        if (it != this->cend()) {
            return it->first;
        } else {
            throw std::out_of_range("value not found");
        }
    }
private:
    using map_t = typename map<K,V>;
    using iter_t = typename map_t::const_iterator;
    iter_t lookup(iter_t first, const V &v) const {
        using val_t = typename map_t::value_type;
        return std::find_if(first, this->cend(), 
[&](const val_t e){ return e.second == v; }); // <-- e doesn't give autosuggestion for second
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: How do you expect Intellisense to give a suggestion at that location as the type of `K` and `V` is unknown at those points?

Comment: @Phil1970 True it doesn't make much sense. But I thought that since the names of the member functions/variables are still the same (with different signature of course after being templated) that Intellisense would be able to show suggestions e.g. `V std::pair<const K, V>::second`. But maybe that's not how it works.

Comment: Also, it is not wise to have a function named `at` that works in reverse order (that the inherited one). Also, one should not derive from most `std` classes. Those things make your code error prone in some situations. In a case like your, it would be much better to write a free function that works on `[unordered_][multi]map`.

Comment: Btw: There is [Boost.Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) (in case you were looking for a ready-to-use solution). But I'm not really familiar with it, so no opinion on the library :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliSense is unable to give names of members which are dependent on template parameter types. Example: A certain member function might exist for most template parameter types but for certain types the class might have a specialization that has no such function defined. Since we haven't provided any concrete types yet IntelliSense is unable to know beforehand if such function name is available.

A way to get by is to give the template concrete types temporarily. Visual Code 2019 seems to have a Template IntelliSense which allows you to switch out the template parameter types for concrete ones. Unfortunately Visual Studio Code does not currently have this feature.